# JavaScript to check all boxes in page but main code "boxe" is different

Tags: javascript

I copy the JS code to check all boxes in page but in search article page the element type is different. Can you help me to solve this?

Normal code:

```js
(function () {
  var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    aa[i].checked = true;
  }
})();
```

Code that shows the article is not in the folder (Obtained in inspect element)

```js
document.querySelector("#resultListControl > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > div > div > span > span > span > label.folder-toggle-label.folder-toggle-label-not-in-folder")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? "in search article page the element type is different" - I didn't get that part at all.

Comment: Your question is not understandable as it. Please provide the minimum JS/HTML so your case can be reproduced, and explain clearly what is the result you want and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to accomplish. Yet, here are some ideas that might help you get started.

Your "normal code" will find and check all boxes.  However, your other css selectors are overly complicated and do not select any checkboxes.  To make them select checkboxes you must add `input[type=checkbox]` to the end of each one like so:

```
#resultListControl > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div > div > span > span > span > label.folder-toggle-label.folder-toggle-label-in-folder input[type=checkbox]
```

And each of the selectors may (optionally) be simplified as there's no need to list every child element selector:

```
#resultListControl li:nth-child(3)  label.folder-toggle-label-in-folder input[type=checkbox]
```

Have a look at the code snippet below for ideas.  And having a good understanding of how selectors work might be helpful. See:  [MDN CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

If this is not what you wanted then you'll need to add more detail to your question so that we understand it better.

```js
var s0 = "input[type=checkbox]";

var s1 = "#resultListControl > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > div > div > span > span > span > label.folder-toggle-label.folder-toggle-label-not-in-folder input[type=checkbox]";

var s2 = "#resultListControl > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div > div > span > span > span > label.folder-toggle-label.folder-toggle-label-in-folder input[type=checkbox]";

var s3 = "#resultListControl li:nth-child(3)  label.folder-toggle-label-in-folder input[type=checkbox]";




function toggle(cssSelector) {
  var aa = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);

  for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    aa[i].checked = !aa[i].checked;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Toggle Checkbox:
<button onclick="toggle(s0)">All</button>
<button onclick="toggle(s1)">Not In Folder</button>
<button onclick="toggle(s2)">In Folder</button>
<button onclick="toggle(s3)">In Folder (Alt)</button>

<div id="resultListControl">
  <div>
    <ul>
    
      <li>1 <input type="checkbox" /></li>
      
      <li>2 <input type="checkbox" /></li>
      
      <li>3
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <span>
                <span>
                  <label class="folder-toggle-label folder-toggle-label-in-folder">
                      <input type="checkbox"/>
                  </label>
                        </span>
            </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>4
        <div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <span>
                <span>
                  <label class="folder-toggle-label folder-toggle-label-not-in-folder">
                      <input type="checkbox"/>
                  </label>
                        </span>
            </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>


    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```